# An analogue to Cantor's theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's theorem states that for all sets $$|A| < |2^A|$$

I was interested in a similar proposition. If $A$ is a set, denote by $A! := \{f : A \rightarrow A \mid f \text{ is a bijection}\}$. Is it true in general that $|A| < |A!|$?

It is not to difficult to show that $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{N}!|$. To see this, let $B \subset \mathbb{N!}$ be the set of permutations which are either the identity or have some number of even naturals swapped with their right neighbor. (0 1 (3 2) 4 5 (7 6) 8 9 10 11 12 ... is an example). Then $B$ is uncountable because if we map unswapped pairs to 0 and swapped pairs to 1, this constitutes a bijective mapping into the set of infinite binary strings, which we know to be uncountable by the classic diagonalization argument. Then as $B \subset \mathbb N!$, $\mathbb N!$ is uncountable.

Unfortunately this proof does not yield an approach to the general case. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not true when $A$ has one or two elements.

Comment: Say the question is whether $|A| \leq |A!|$, then. Or better yet say A is infinite as that is the interesting case.

Comment: $|A|\le|A!|$ is easy: fix $a\in A$, there's an obvious bijection between $A$ and the set of all transpositions $(a,x)$ plus the identity permutation. It's $|A|\lt|A!|$ that's the interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a hint from Unit’s comment down below (ultimately coming from *Factorials of Infinite Cardinals* by Dawson and Howard, it seems), here’s a case differentiation proving the result in ZF (as far as I can tell).

> **In case $|A| = |2 × A|$**: Mapping $2^A → (2×A)!,~ B ↦ σ_B$, where $σ_B$ swaps the two copies of $B$ in $2×A  = A \sqcup A$ pointwise and fixes the rest, is injective. If $2×A \cong A$ you have $(2×A)! \cong A!$ and hence this proves $|A| < |2^A| ≤ |A!|$.
>
> **In case $|A| < |2 × A|$**: Assume $|A| > 2$ and fix a two element set $2_A ⊂ A$ and a check-point $ξ ∈ A\setminus2_A$. Then the mapping $2_A×A → A!,~(α,x) ↦ (α~ξ~x)$ is evidently left-inverted by $A! → 2_A×A,~τ ↦ (τ^{-1}(ξ),τ(ξ))$, hence it’s injective, proving $|A| < |2×A| ≤ |A!|$.

I hope this is correct.

Comment: $2\times A\cong A$ is true given the Axiom of Choice, but I don't think it is necessarily true without AC. It would be interesting to see if the result could be proved _without_ AC.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I know, that’s what I’m trying to improve. ;-) Maybe using version (2). I’m trying to find an argument for the existence of such a $σ$ without choice. Edit: Oh, it’s not?

Comment: @Henning: It's not, and that topic has been discussed before too. :-)

Comment: Have a look at *Factorials of infinite cardinals* by Dawson and Howard.

Comment: For version 2, I see no reason why $\sigma|_{B^c}\cup \mathrm{id}_B$ would be a bijection. Does $\sqcup$ (whose meaning in this context I'm not sure of) somehow fix that?

Comment: In particular, "In the absence of the axiom of choice, any one of the three alternatives (i) $X!$ and $2^X$ are incomparable, (ii) $X! > 2^X$, or (iii) $X! < 2^X$ are possible."

Comment: @Unit: Actually, there is a paper by David Pincus which deals with this topic, "A note on the cardinal factorial" (Fundamenta Mathematicae vol.98(1), pages 21-24(1978)) which is a nice workout without choice.

Comment: Slightly confused here - I'm unfamiliar with the notation $2 \times A$ and $A \sqcup A$. What do these mean? I imagine the former is $\{0,1\} \times A$

Comment: @dalastboss Yes, all of them are supposed to mean $\{0,1\} × A$. (I’m neither a logician nor a set theoriest, though, so my notation might be off.) But have a look at wiki on [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) and [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Category_theory_point_of_view).

Comment: @Unit: What do they say about $X\lt X!$? Is that provable without choice, or is $X=X!$ possible?

Comment: Theorem 1.1 says if $|X| \ge 3$ then $|X| < |X!|$. Since it is true in ZF that $|X| \le |2\times X|$, they proceed by cases: "if $|X| < |2\times X|$", and "if $|X| = |2\times X|$".